# APL Identities in Progressive Index Idiom

Tags: algorithm, sorting, apl

Idioms #1 and #5 is the [FinnAPL Idiom Library](http://aplwiki.com/FinnAplIdiomLibrary) both have the same name: “Progressive index of (without replacement)”:

```
((⍴X)⍴⍋⍋X⍳X,Y)⍳(⍴Y)⍴⍋⍋X⍳Y,X             ⍝ idiom #1
((⍋X⍳X,Y)⍳⍳⍴X)⍳(⍋X⍳Y,X)⍳⍳⍴Y             ⍝ idiom #5
```

Are there any important indentities underlying this duplicity?

**Side Note:**

The emphasis on identities in APL has been one of the characteristics that has distinguished APL since the beginning. Kenneth Iverson, the creator of APL, said:

*”An identity is an equivalence between two different expressions. Although identities are commonly thought of only as tools of mathematical analysis, they can be an important practical tool for simplfying and otherwise modifying expressions used in defining functions.”*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These idioms have a few things in common. The final step for both is an index-of operation, they both use sort of a mirrored concatenation strategy, and perhaps most importantly, the output of the left and right arguments is the same for both. That simplifies the search for an identity quite a bit, because we can compare the right argument of #1 with the right argument of of #5:

```
(⍴Y)⍴⍋⍋X⍳Y,X                ⍝ right arg #1
(⍋X⍳Y,X)⍳⍳⍴Y                ⍝ right arg #5
```

Another thing that can simplify the search is getting rid of or modifying anything that truncates the output, because the output of both  arguments is the same without truncating. Idiom # 1 uses `(⍴Y)⍴` to truncate it to the length of `Y`, and the length of right argument in idiom #5 depends on the length of `Y` in `⍳⍴Y`. In the first case, the truncation can be removed, and in the second, it can be modified to the full length of `Y,X` :

```
⍋⍋X⍳Y,X                     ⍝ #1
(⍋X⍳Y,X)⍳⍳⍴Y,X              ⍝ #5
```

Given that both expressions contain `⍋X⍳Y,X`, let's assign that to a variable `A ← ⍋X⍳Y,X` and simplify. However, it's important to point out that the identity we have now only applies if A is a permutation vector, and I'll be talking more about that later. In the meantime, we have this identity:

```
⍋A ←→ A⍳⍳⍴Y,X
```

Since ´Y,X´ does nothing in this expression except for provide the vector length, and since that length is equal to ´A´, the identity can be simplified to its final form:

```
⍋A ←→ A⍳⍳⍴A, where A is a permutation vector
```

This makes a lot of sense. The grade-up operator, on the left side of the identity, returns the index values that each value of `A` would have if it were assorted in ascending order. The index-of operator, on the right, returns the index in A where the ascending values of `⍳⍴A` are located. For example:

```
5 2 1 4 3                   ⍝ A←5 2 1 4 3
3 2 5 4 1                   ⍝ ⍋A

5 2 1 4 3                   ⍝ A←5 2 1 4 3
1 2 3 4 5                   ⍝ ⍳⍴A
3 2 5 4 1                   ⍝ A⍳⍳⍴A
```

Looking at the last two rows, the 1 has an index of 3 in A, 2 has 2, 3 has 5, 4 has 4 and the final 5 has an index of 1. That makes sense because that is pretty much by definition what the grade-up operator does.

**Permutation Vectors**

As already said, this identity is only valid if A is a permutation vector. In his essay *Notation as a Tool of Thought* , Kenneth Iverson defined a permutation vector: “A vector P whose elements are some permutation of its indices (that is, ^/1=+/P∘.=⍳⍴P) will be called a permutation vector.” Looking at some of the idioms themselves, you can see this idea represented in various ways:

```
Y[⍋Y]^.=X[⍋X]           #6 permutations of each other 
X^.=⍋⍋X                 #7 test if permutation vector
X[⍋X]^.=⍳⍴X             #29 test if permutation vector
⍋X                      #48 Inverting a permutation 
X⍳⍳⍴X                   #212 Inverting a permutation
^/1=+⌿X∘.=⍳⍴X           #281 test if permutation vector
^/(⍳⍴X)∊X               #454 test if permutation vector
A←⍳⍴X ⋄ A[X]←A ⋄ A      #654 Inverting a permutation
```

In idiom #7, the right side of the expression is the ascending cardinal numbers idiom, which I discussed in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383435/ascending-cardinal-numbers-in-apl), and in that post I talked about the fact that the grade up operator switches back and forth between two states, rank and index, such that we have the following two identities:

```
⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋⍋⍋X ...
⍋⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋⍋⍋⍋X ...
```

That second identity could be extend as follows, if X is a permutation vector as idiom #7 establishes:

```
X ←→ ⍋⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋⍋X ←→ ⍋⍋⍋⍋⍋⍋X …
```

We know that the grade-up operator returns all the numbers from 1 to the number of values in the argument. Apply the grade-up operator two more times and you get the exact same vector in the same order. Therefore idiom #7 is just saying that a permutation vector is one which contains all the numbers from 1 to some other value once and only once. (This assumes that 1 is set as the first index value.)

Another thing that is interesting about the list of idioms above is that idiom #48 and #212 are the left and right sides of the identity discussed in the answer:

```
⍋A ←→ A⍳⍳⍴Y,X
```